# Presto cluster + how to tune the jvm.config according to memory resources

Tags: java, linux, performance, presto

we are using presto cluster as distributed SQL query

**our cluster size**

1 machine as coordinator machine

12 presto workers machines

each machine is 64G memory size , and on each machine only presto application installed

about the `jvm.config` on the workers , look like this

```
-server
-Xmn10G
-Xmx50G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

and the `jvm.config` on the presto coordinator , like like this

```
-server
-Xmn4096M
-Xmx30G
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=600M
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10
-XX:+UseG1GC
```

we set the `Xmn` and `Xmx` values as above , 
but this setting is only estimation

can we get help how to tune the Xmn and Xmx according to MAX memory - 64G
so presto cluster performance will tune to the best practice sizing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, there is no reason to set `-Xmn` (size of young gen), because the JVM will tune this size at run-time. Or, in other words, you have to have good reasons to set `-Xmn`.

`-Xmx` -- you basically want to tell the JVM it can use all of the memory, but at the same time need to account for non-heap memory in JVM (certain buffers, GC data structures, etc.) and memory occupied by OS-level services. In Presto case, as a rule of thumb you typically set `-Xmx` to 80% of available memory and tune it later, based on your monitoring of your workloads.

Regarding other properties you set:

- `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` is redundant (CMS garbage colelctor is not used, G1 is, as per `-XX:+UseG1GC` flag)
- `-XX:+AggressiveOpts` is unlikely something you want to set
- `-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio`, `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio` -- if Presto is the only service on the box, you don't want to set these
- you're missing some recommended properties (and we recommend each of them for a reason). See https://trino.io/docs/current/installation/deployment.html#jvm-config

Comment: thank you , regarding to what you said , so I need simply to remiove the line ->  -Xmn10G from the file ? or any other additional lines in the file - jvm.config

Comment: Yes, remove `-Xmn...` line from the file. Regarding other properties -- i expanded my answer to cover them too.